# Why does water in spinning bucket move out outward if centripetal and centrifugal forces cancel out?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Evey source I saw keeps saying change in shape of water is due to centrifugal force but it cancels out with centripetal force
And if you see from inertial frame of reference the water shouldn't moving just like an object in accelerating bus does not move with respect to inertial frame but moves according to passenger
Not taking friction

Comment: More on [centripetal & centrifugal forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/centripetal-force+centrifugal-force).

Answer (score 3):

Copying [from here](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Centrifugal_Force_vs_Centripetal_Force)

> Centrifugal force (Latin for "center fleeing") describes the tendency of an object following a curved path to fly outwards, away from the center of the curve. *It's not really a force; it results from inertia — the tendency of an object to resist any change in its state of rest or motion.* Centripetal force is *a real force* that counteracts the centrifugal force and prevents the object from "flying out," keeping it moving instead with a uniform speed along a circular path.

Italics mine for emphasis.

In the spinning bucket the real force, i.e giving a dp/dt to the liquid, the centripetal, comes from the friction of the walls of the bucket with the molecules of the liquid, kicking them  continually into the circular path. The energy is supplied by what is spinning the bucket.

For a full bucket, the spinning bulk liquid has a centripetal force *transferred through the bulk by the cohesion of the liquid* and the same logic holds: the molecules by inertia would go in straight lines. the centripetal force turns them into circular or vortex path.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Centripetal and Centrifugal forces are the same. It only depends on the frame of refrence of the observer. They can exist simultaneously. Centrifugal force is centripetal force but in the frame of accelerating object rather than being a inward force it becomes a outward force and that is centrifugal force.(You can say that it's a Pseudo Force.).

Comment: My question is different read description

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on the assumption that centripetal force and centrifugal force "cancel out." But, they don't cancel out because they are just two different names for the same thing.

When we describe the experiment in terms of an inertial reference frame, we see a person pulling on (exerting a force on) a rope, the rope exerting a force on the bucket, the bucket exerting a force on the water. All of those forces pull the water toward the person, preventing the water from flying away in a straight line.

We call that force, "centripetal."

Issac Newton said that for every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction. What he meant was, We can think of the bucket exerting a force on the water, or we can think of the water exerting an equal and opposite force on the bucket. It amounts to the same thing either way. Really, it's *one* force acting *between* the bucket and the water.

In the inertial reference frame, our attention is focused on how the person at the center seems to be pulling the water toward themself.
But, when we describe the experiment in terms of a rotating frame—a frame in which the bucket and the person are stationary—we see a different picture. The same force acts between the bucket and the water, but it seems magical because nothing in the picture is moving. The water just seems to mysteriously want to fly away from the person at the coordinate system origin if the person and the rope and the bucket did not hold it back.

When we focus our attention on the force of the water pulling against the bucket, we call that "centrifugal."  But, it's the same force *pair* in either case. So, nothing cancels. A force can't cancel itself.

Comment: Maybe my wording is wrong
What I am saying is when you shift to inertial frame net force becomes zero like an object in an accelerating truck for someone in truck it appears to move in opposite direction to motion of truck(caused by inertial force)
But for someone outside it doesn't move
My question why is water moving for someone seeing it from inertial frame

Comment: @DeepakVss, Why the bucket moves in an inertial frame is also why the bucket moves in _most_ frames. It's because the bucket is moving _in reality._ Why the bucket does _not_ move in one particular rotating frame is because we carefully chose that frame such that the coordinates of the bucket do not change with time. (I.e., it does not move _relative to that special frame.)

Comment: P.S., What's special about inertial frames is, in _any_ inertial frame, we can explain that the force between the bucket and the person at the center is due to the person pulling against the _inertia_ of the bucket. There also is a simple law to explain the force in the one, carefully chosen, rotating frame where the bucket does not move: Everything in that frame is pulled away from the origin by "centrifugal force." But that law does not generalize to other frames, and so it does not help us to understand the reality. That's why we call the mysterious centrifugal force a "pseudo force."